# How to make selecatable false in kendo ui grid using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Please let me know if it possible to make selectable attribute of kendo ui grid to false by using jquery.

I have two grids 1st grid is selectable true when i make changes to 1st grid the 2nd grid selectable functionality should change accordingly 
suppose there are two category in the grid rows one of the row is admin and other row is normal user then if it is normal user the 2nd grid selectable should get true by using jquery outside the grid...

```
`jQuery("#usersMatterList").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: usersMatterDataSource,
                    autobind:false,
                    filterable: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    pageable: false,
                    resizable: true,
                    selectable : true,
                    scrollable: true,
                    change : function(e){
                      var selectedItem = this.dataItem(this.select());

                      if(selectedItem.id != null){
                        globalCaseId = selectedItem.id;
                        updateAllPermissionComboboxes(globalCaseId);
                      }
                    },
                    columns: [
                      { 
                        name : 'id', 
                        field : 'id', 
                        hidden : true
                      },
                      { 
                        name : 'name', 
                        field : 'name', 
                        align: "left"
                      },
                      { 
                        name : 'deleteIcon', 
                        field : 'deleteIcon', 
                        align: 'left',
                        title: 'Delete',
                        template: function (cellvalue) {
                          return "<span class='deleteIconClass'><img border='0' src='${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'close_icon9x8.png')}' alt='Delete' title='Delete' style='cursor: pointer'/></span>";
                        },
                        width:25,
                        hidden: true
                      },
                    ],
                    dataBound: function(e) {
                        jQuery(".deleteIconClass").click(function(evt){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            deleteAskKendoWindow.data("kendoWindow").center().open();
                        });
                        //console.log(this.selectable);
                        if(this.options.selectable){

                          this.select(e.sender.tbody.find("tr:first"));
                        }

                    }
                    //filterMenuInit: onFilterMenuInit
                }).data("kendoGrid");`
```

I tried to change in below shown manner

```
if(user.companyAdmin || user.siteAdmin){

                  //jQuery("#usersMatterList").find('table').removeClass("k-selectable");
                  //jQuery("#usersMatterList").data("kendoGrid").options.selectable = false;
                  //
                  //jQuery("#usersMatterList").removeClass('k-selectable');   

                  //jQuery("#usersMatterList").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read(); 
                  //ugrid.refresh();
                  //jQuery("#usersMatterList").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
                }else if(!user.companyAdmin || !user.siteAdmin) {
                  //jQuery("#usersMatterList").find('table').addClass("k-selectable");
                  //jQuery("#usersMatterList").addClass('k-selectable');  
                  //jQuery("#usersMatterList").data("kendoGrid").options.selectable = true;
                  //grid.refresh();
                  //jQuery("#usersMatterList").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the grid's setOptions method

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setOptions

```
var grid = $("#usersMatterList").data("kendoGrid");
grid.setOptions({
    selectable: false
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/EReJa)**

Comment: Hey! thanks sir its working...You made my day! i m new to kendo so i was literally stuck!!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to disable by using jQuery-ui

i actually removed the classes where the kendo ui grid was adding the k-selectable

```
if(user.companyAdmin == 1 || user.siteAdmin){

              jQuery("#usersMatterList").removeClass("k-selectable");
              jQuery("#usersMatterList").find("tr").removeClass("k-state-selected");

              //jQuery("#usersMatterList").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
              //jQuery("#usersMatterList").data("kendoGrid").options.selectable = false;
            }
            else
            {
              jQuery("#usersMatterList").addClass("k-selectable");
              //jQuery("#usersMatterList").data("kendoGrid").options.selectable = true;  
            }
```

its working now thanks all visitors. If there is any other solutions can provide me. Thank you.